# How to link an external JSX file, but render in the actual document

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm having trouble finding the answer to this. I have an external jsx file that contains my React components, and then I have a babel script in the document itself that's calling the render function, but it can't see the components. Is this an incorrect way to render external JSX? I want to do it this way so I can call the render on different components on different pages, and so I can pass PHP variables through the properties onRender.

Here's the setup of my document. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/babel" src="../../js/modules/tagDrawer.jsx"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(
      <TagButton renderTags="true"/>,
      document.getElementById("tag-wrapper")
    );
</script>
```

PS, I'm using browser.js to render JSX in the client while I'm developing.

Comment: For this to work, `../../js/modules/tagDrawer.jsx` would have to define a global variable with name `TagButton`, and of course Babel would have to be set up to run in the browser (which is discouraged anyway). Is that the case?

Comment: Babel is setup to run in the browser at the moment just for development. I plan to precompile later. As for the global variable, I have them declared in the JSX file as `var TagButton = React.createClass({etc...})` Is that enough to put them in the global scope?

Comment: Yep, that should work. There is nothing special about a JSX file, except some syntax extensions. It still works like any other JavaScript file. However, maybe Babel does something and treats every file as a module. You could try `window.TagButton = ...` instead.

Comment: @FelixKling I just keep getting `TagButton is not defined`. Do you have any theories why it can't access my components?

Comment: No `var` will not work. Script tags with type `text/babel` have their own scopes. it will work if you add the component to the `window` however, ie: `window.TagButton = `

Comment: @azium Are you meaning in my JSX file I need to define my component as `var window.TagButton` ? Doing that throws an error, I'm kind of new to javascript so I'm not sure how to do what you're describing.

Comment: @azium Actually I got that working. That works perfectly for what I'm doing at the moment. Thanks for the help. If you put that in an answer I'll mark it as correct.